# application-name has encountered a p‌r‌o‌b‌l‌e‌m and needs to close. We are sorry for the inconvenience error when running Qt app on xp

Tags: c++, qt, deployment, windows-7, windows-xp

I have this piece of code that takes a ppt document and transforms it to a series of images I want to integrate into my Qt application .

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include "msword.h"
#include "ExcelToPic.h"
#include "ppttopic.h"
#include "WordToPic.h"


......
void Widget::on_transformButton_clicked()
{
//DO THE BULK OF YOUR TRANSFORMATIONS HERE


   QString filepath=ui->chooseDocLineEdit->text();
   QString outDir=ui->outputLocationLineEdit->text();

   QFileInfo mFile(filepath);
   QString filename=mFile.baseName();

   QString fileExt=mFile.suffix();


   //TRANSFORM THOSE INTO CSTRINGS.


   QByteArray destBa1 = filepath.toLocal8Bit();
   const char *filepathCString1 = destBa1.data();
   CString strFilePath(filepathCString1,destBa1.size());




   QByteArray destBa4 = outDir.toLocal8Bit();
   const char *outDirCString1 = destBa4.data();
   CString szOutDir(outDirCString1,destBa4.size());



                PowerPointToPic(strFilePath, szOutDir,outDir);



            QMessageBox message;
            message.setText("Transformtion successful");
            message.exec();

}
```

The PowerPointToPic function is implemented as follows:

```
void PowerPointToPic(CString szDocName, CString szOutDir,QString outDir)
{

 CPPTApplication m_powerpointApp;
 CPPTPresentations m_powerpointPres;
 CPPTPresentation m_powerpointPre;
 CPPTSlide    slide;
 CPPTSlides       slides;
 m_powerpointPres.ReleaseDispatch();
 m_powerpointPre.ReleaseDispatch();


 try{
  CoInitialize(NULL);
  if(!m_powerpointApp.CreateDispatch(_T("PowerPoint.Application"), NULL))
  {
   //AfxMessageBox(_T("创建PowerPoint服务失败!"));
   return;
  }
 }
 catch(...)
 {
  return;
 }

 m_powerpointApp.m_bAutoRelease=true;
 m_powerpointApp.put_Visible(long(1));
 m_powerpointApp.put_WindowState(long(2));
 m_powerpointPres.AttachDispatch(m_powerpointApp.get_Presentations());
 m_powerpointPres.Open(szDocName,TRUE, 1, 1);
 m_powerpointPre.AttachDispatch(m_powerpointApp.get_ActivePresentation(),TRUE);

 slides = m_powerpointPre.get_Slides();

 int pageCount = slides.get_Count();
 for( int i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++ )
 {
  slide  = slides.Range(COleVariant((long)i));
  slide.Copy();

  //_T("c:\\test-%d.bmp")

        //CString temp;

        //QString sohokafile="sohokaImage"+QString::number(i);

        QString sohokafile=outDir+"/sohokaImage"+QString::number(i)+".png";

        QByteArray destBa4 = sohokafile.toLocal8Bit();
        const char *outDirCString1 = destBa4.data();
        CString temp(outDirCString1,destBa4.size());



       //slide.Export(_T("c:\\amaImages\\slide1.png"), _T("png"),900,900 );
        slide.Export(temp, _T("png"),900,900 );



 }

 m_powerpointPre.Close();
 m_powerpointApp.Quit();
 m_powerpointPre.ReleaseDispatch();
 m_powerpointPres.ReleaseDispatch();
 slides.ReleaseDispatch();
 slide.ReleaseDispatch();
 m_powerpointApp.ReleaseDispatch();

 CoUninitialize();

}
```

When I wrap this into a test widget application to see if all works as expected the code turns the ppt document into png images on both win7 and winxp without problems. But when I integrate it within my Qt app ,It only runs on win7 without problems and throws the [application name] has encountered a problem and needs to close. We are sorry for the inconvenience error.

From my search [superuser.com] this is probably due to incompatibilities I can’t figure out .I also updated my virtual machine xp system to no avail.The application links to normal Qt 4 dlls and a few other third party libraries.

I would appreciate it if somebody helped with this .Thank you for your time.

Comment: Why exactly don't you debug your application to figure out the offending place? Anyway, you have not really shared the setup with us on both platforms...

Comment: Debugging so far shows me that the app fails at this line slide.Export(temp, _T("png"),900,900 ) ,looking into possible reasons .My dev machine set up is Win7 Qt 4.8.6 msvs 2010 ,I am testing both on win7 and winxp and this error is only appearing on xp .